# how to email form information using mandrill

Tags: javascript, html, email, mandrill

I've created a website that has a form with multiple fields and i'm trying to get the button to actually email me the information entered. I have been trying to learn about the Mandrill API on code academy, but I may be open to other methods that accomplish the same task. Here's what i have so far:

```
<div id="contactUs">
    <div class="container">

    <div class="row form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address">
        </div><!-- end col-sm-6 -->

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control" id="organization" placeholder="Organization or Company Name">
        </div><!-- end col-sm-6 -->

    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <div class="row form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div><!-- end col-sm-6 -->

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
        </div><!-- end col-sm-6 -->

    </div><!-- end form-group -->

    <div class="row form-group">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button onclick="sendTheMail(); return false;" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="alertMe">Contact Us</button>
        </div><!-- end col-sm-6 -->

    </div><!-- end form-group -->
</div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end contactUs -->
```

And the JS..

```
// create a variable for the API call parameters
var params = {
    "message": {
        "from_email":"staticallyanyone@anywhere.net",
        "to":[{"email":"myemail@hotmail.com"}],
        "subject": "An Inquiry from your website",
        "text": "Static text.. but how do i link the information entered in the fields to show up here?"
    }
};

function sendTheMail() {
// Send the email!

    m.messages.send(params);
}
```

There must be a way to link the info from the fields into the JS?.. im a rookie still.. any tips to get better at js .. pls let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab elements by their id and get the value from the element. The code below should work. I believe Mandrill allows html messages so if you want you can spruce the html up in the emailBody variable to make a more attractive email.

```
function sendTheMail() {
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
var organization = document.getElementById('organization').value;
var emailBody = "<b>Email: </b>" + email + "<br><b>Name: </b>" + name + "<br><b>Phone: </b>" + phone + "<br><b>Organization: </b>" + organization;
var params = {
"message": {
    "from_email":"staticallyanyone@anywhere.net",
    "to":[{"email":"myemail@hotmail.com"}],
    "subject": "An Inquiry from your website",
    "text": emailBody
    }
};
m.messages.send(params);
```

}

Comment: i will have to try this later tonight when i have the time.. but thanks a ton if this works!

Comment: i got your html to work by changing: "text": emailBody --> "html": emailBody ... thanks again!